# OS-Uninstaller saying I will need to update my bootloader?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uninstall, bootloader

I am following these instructions to remove Ubuntu 13.10 from my system:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OS-Uninstaller

But when I run os-uninstaller instead of just saying it will remove the Ubuntu 13.10 it also says I will need to update my bootloader. I thought the point of this tool was so that it removes the OS and does everything else automatically?

I am unsure how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

The program is telling you simply that it will remove the entry from the bootloader for the operating system it is removing. It is supposed to do that. However, proceed with caution (back up any necessary files) since bootloader operations, if done wrong, can damage your bootloader and will make your system unbootable.